# Angular - How can I change the data downloaded from JSONA depending on the options in the selection

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, http

Component HTML

```
 <div>
  <select name="cos">
   <option selected="selected" >Wybierz kino</option>
   <option *ngFor="let kino of kina  "[value]="kino.id">{{ kino.name }} | {{ kino.id }}</option>
  </select>

  <div *ngIf="kino.id" *ngFor="let kin of kina.cinemaProgramme.programmeItems" style="color:white;">
    {{ kin.movie.title }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Component TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProgrammeService } from '../programme.service';
import { Time } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-repertuar',
  templateUrl: './repertuar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./repertuar.component.css']
})
export class RepertuarComponent implements OnInit {

   film: CinemaProgramme[];
   repertuar: CinemaProgramme[];
   kina: Cinema[];
   programy: Array<ProgrammeItems> = [];

  getCinemaProgramme(): void {
    this.programmeService.getCinemaProgramme().
    subscribe(repertuar => this.repertuar = repertuar);
  }

  getCinema(): void {
    this.programmeService.getCinema().
    subscribe(kina => this.kina = kina);
  }

  getCinemaPrograme(): void {
    this.programmeService.getCinemaPrograme().
    subscribe(film => this.film = film);
  }

  getRepertuar(): void {
    this.programmeService.getRepertuar().
    subscribe(programy => this.programy =  programy);
  }

  constructor(private programmeService: ProgrammeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCinemaProgramme();
    this.getCinema();
  }
}

export interface Cinema {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  cinemaProgramme: CinemaProgramme;
 }

export interface CinemaProgramme {
  id: number;
  programmeItems: Array<ProgrammeItems> ;
}

export interface ProgrammeItems {
  movie: Movie;
  hours: Date[];
 }

export interface Movie {
   id?: number;
   title?: string;
   director?: string;
   length?: Time;
   description?: string;
 }
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ProgrammeItems, CinemaProgramme, Cinema } from './repertuar/repertuar.component';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ProgrammeService {
  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/';

  getCinemaPrograme(): Observable<CinemaProgramme[]> {
    return this.http.get<CinemaProgramme[]>(this.url + 'cinema/getAll');
  }

  getCinemaProgramme(): Observable<CinemaProgramme[]> {
    return this.http.get<CinemaProgramme[]>('http://localhost:8080/programme/get/6');
  }

  getCinema(): Observable<Cinema[]> {
    return this.http.get<Cinema[]>('http://localhost:8080/cinema/getAll');
  }

  getRepertuar(): Observable<Array<ProgrammeItems>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<ProgrammeItems>>(this.url + 'programme/getAll');
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

I was thinking about getting the cinema id (cinema_name)
which would be in [value] = "kina.id"
and apply it to dependencies in displaying a given repertoire but even JSON's properties from the second ngfora are not displayed at all: / How should I do it ?? ;/

And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second div (second ngFor) is not displayed because you have `*ngIf="kino.id"` but kino is only defined inside

`<option *ngFor="let kino of kina  "[value]="kino.id">{{ kino.name }} | {{ kino.id }}</option>`

and each option created has it's own `kino.id`. But outside the option kino is undefined. So your condition is false. If you want to check the value selected in your div (second `*ngFor`) you should declare a variable in your ts a variable to keep the selected id. So something like:

```
   film: CinemaProgramme[];
   repertuar: CinemaProgramme[];
   kina: Cinema[];
   programy: Array<ProgrammeItems> = [];
   selectedKinoId: "";
   _______________________
```

and than use it in your selector like this:

`<select [(ngModel)]="selectedKinoId" name="cos">...</select>`

and your condition in the div with the second *ngIf would become:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedKinoId"
```

Please also note that `kina.cinemaProgramme` does not exists since kina is an array of Cinema elements. So you will probably need a function to get the cinema by id.

I would recoment adding a function like this to your Component TS:

```
getCinemaById(id){
  for(let kin of kina) {
    if(kin.id == id) {
      return kin;
    }
  }
}
```

So div with the second `*ngIf` would become

```
<div *ngIf="selectedKinoId" *ngFor="let kin of getCinemaById(selectedKinoId).cinemaProgramme.programmeItems" style="color:white;">
  {{ kin.movie.title }}
</div>
```

Comment: Yeyyy !! IT works ! thanks nice man !! :))  But i needed  add one more div  ```<div *ngIf="selectedKinoId">....div with NGFOR</div>```